# Changing axis on google visualization line chart is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am working on a google visualization where the data being returned can have more than 2 axis.  If there are more than 2, I only show the first 2 coming back and provide a control for switching the axis.

Here is my work in progress...
http://jsfiddle.net/benstraw/Lx7w0jgL/

```
    //Load the Visualisation API and the package you want to use
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});

//Set a callback to run with the API is loaded
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.
function drawChart() {

    jsonData = {"cols":[{"id":"col_1","label":"Date","type":"string","_cct":{"datatype":"Text","icuFormat":null}},{"id":"col_2","label":"Sum of DEP1","type":"number","_cct":{"datatype":"Curency","icuFormat":"$#,###.##"}},{"id":"col_3","label":"Sum of DEP14","type":"number","_cct":{"datatype":"Curency","icuFormat":"$#,###.##"}},{"id":"col_4","label":"Sum of DEP60","type":"number","_cct":{"datatype":"Curency","icuFormat":"$#,###.##"}},{"id":"col_5","label":"Sum of FDEP","type":"number","_cct":{"datatype":"Number","icuFormat":"#,###"}},{"id":"col_6","label":"Avg of FDEP7 Rate","type":"number","_cct":{"datatype":"Percentage","icuFormat":"#.##%"}},{"id":"col_7","label":"Avg of FDEP14 Rate","type":"number","_cct":{"datatype":"Percentage","icuFormat":"#.##%"}},{"id":"col_8","label":"Sum of DEP90","type":"number","_cct":{"datatype":"Curency","icuFormat":"$#,###.##"}}], "rows":[{"c": [{"v":"\"2015-01-01\"","f":"\"2015-01-01\""},{"v":1619.67,"f":"$1,619.67"},{"v":4217.28,"f":"$4,217.28"},{"v":8092.95,"f":"$8,092.95"},{"v":105,"f":"105"},{"v":0.001429,"f":"0.14%"},{"v":0.001531,"f":"0.15%"},{"v":8588.57,"f":"$8,588.57"}]}, {"c": [{"v":"\"2015-01-02\"","f":"\"2015-01-02\""},{"v":3739.06,"f":"$3,739.06"},{"v":10520.47,"f":"$10,520.47"},{"v":16519.71,"f":"$16,519.71"},{"v":128,"f":"128"},{"v":0.001506,"f":"0.15%"},{"v":0.001653,"f":"0.17%"},{"v":17160.87,"f":"$17,160.87"}] }, {"c": [{"v":"\"2015-01-03\"","f":"\"2015-01-03\""},{"v":3423.92,"f":"$3,423.92"},{"v":8905.73,"f":"$8,905.73"},{"v":13813.97,"f":"$13,813.97"},{"v":119,"f":"119"},{"v":0.001433,"f":"0.14%"},{"v":0.001495,"f":"0.15%"},{"v":14773.98,"f":"$14,773.98"}] } ], "_cct":{"query_name":"Query_2015-03-16","query_link":"\/reports\/query_builder\/7"}};
    //create the data table
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    var options = {
    // colors: ['rgb(0, 158, 229)','rgb(228, 59, 0)', 'rgb(228, 0, 229)', '#e2431e', '#f1ca3a', '#6f9654', '#1c91c0', '#4374e0', '#5c3292', '#572a1a', '#999999','rgb(158, 229, 0)', '#1a1a1a'],
    fontSize: 12,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    chartArea: {
      width: '75%',
      height: '75%'
    },
    // width: '100%',
    titleTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 20
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 5
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 1000,
      startup: false,
      easing: 'in'
    },
    crosshair: { 
      trigger: 'both',
      opacity: 0.6, 
      color: 'rgb(228, 59, 0)'
    },
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      gridLines: {color: '#333', count: 6}
    }
  }
    var vAxes = {"0":{"title":"Curency","format":"$#,###.##"},"3":{"title":"Sum of FDEP","format":"#,###"},"4":{"title":"Percentage","format":"#.##%"}}

    var series = {"0":{"targetAxisIndex":0},"1":{"targetAxisIndex":0},"2":{"targetAxisIndex":0},"3":{"targetAxisIndex":3},"6":{"targetAxisIndex":0}}

    // set up the column picker
    var panelData = {"Curency":[{"name":"Sum of DEP1","colId":0,"type":"Curency","targetAxisIndex":0},{"name":"Sum of DEP14","colId":1,"type":"Curency","targetAxisIndex":0},{"name":"Sum of DEP60","colId":2,"type":"Curency","targetAxisIndex":0},{"name":"Sum of DEP90","colId":6,"type":"Curency","targetAxisIndex":0}],"Number":[{"name":"Sum of FDEP","colId":3,"type":"Number","targetAxisIndex":3}],"Percentage":[{"name":"Avg of FDEP7 Rate","colId":4,"type":"Percentage","targetAxisIndex":4},{"name":"Avg of FDEP14 Rate","colId":5,"type":"Percentage","targetAxisIndex":4}]}


    var seriesOpts = { 'series': series }
    options = _.assign(options, seriesOpts)
    var vAxesOpts = { 'vAxes': vAxes }
    options = _.assign(options, vAxesOpts)

    var filterColumns = [5,6]
    var chartView = new google.visualization.DataView(data)
    chartView.hideColumns(filterColumns)
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
        document.getElementById('kpi-chart')
    );
    chart.draw(chartView, options);

    var columnPanel = $('.kpi-controls-panel .column-list')
      _.forEach(panelData, function(n, key) {
        columnPanel.append('<h2>' + key + '</h2>')
        _.forEach(n, function(o, key) {
          //console.log('colProp', o)
          var colRow = $('<div></div>')
          var checkbox = $('<input class="col-cb" type="checkbox" name="column" value="' + o.colId + ':' + o.targetAxisIndex + '"/>')
          var label = o.name + '(' + o.colId + ')'
          if (_.has(series, o.colId)) {
            checkbox.attr('checked', 'checked')
          }
          colRow.append(checkbox)
          colRow.append(label)
          columnPanel.append(colRow)
        })
      })
  var button = $('<p class="button"><a><strong>update columns</strong></a></p>')
  columnPanel.append(button)

  // handle the column update
  $('.kpi-controls-panel .button').click(function(event) {
    console.log('update columns clicked')
    showCols = [0]
    hideCols = []
    options.series = {}
    _.forEach($('.column-list .col-cb'), function(cb, i) {
      var colId = parseInt(cb.value.split(':')[0])
      var tarId = parseInt(cb.value.split(':')[1])
      if (cb.checked) {
        console.log('cb val: ', cb.value)
        showCols.push(parseInt(colId)+1)
        options.series[colId] = {targetAxisIndex: tarId}
        // delete options.series[cb.value+1]
      } else {
        hideCols.push(parseInt(colId)+1)
      }
      console.log('series: ', options.series)
    })
    console.log('showCols', showCols)
    console.log('hideCols', hideCols)
    // var newChart = new google.visualization.DataView(data)
    console.log(options)
    chartView.setColumns(showCols)
    chart.draw(chartView, options)
    var controls = $('.kpi-controls-panel');
    controls.slideToggle(function() {
    });
  })
  $('#kpi-controls-link').click(function(){
    var controls = $('.kpi-controls-panel');
    controls.slideToggle(function() {
    });
  })

}
```

If you turn of the item in the number axis, and turn on the 2 items in the percentage axis the switch happens correctly, but when I switch them back the number axis range is wrong, it has the range for the currency axis.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why, but having the array of column numbers being out of order seemed to be causing problems. I added the line `showCols.sort()` before you call `setColumns` and it appears to have fixed the behavior you described in the question. Here's a forked fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qf8nL24s/1/

Comment: your forked fiddle is not working for me.  i see your sort call, but when I change columns using the column selector The axis get messed up.  Try turning on percentage things and turning off number things and leaving currency as is.

Comment: In the description of your question, you said that turning on percentage and turning off number switched the axis correctly, it was switching them back that caused a problem. I see a change in the axis when doing what you described, but with my sort call, switching them back returns the axis to the way it was.

Comment: You are right, and thank you.  However this is still not working correctly.  If I turn off all of the currency items and turn on number and percentage it loses the right axis altogether.  I will give you the bounty, since you answered the specific part of my first question, but if you have time and understanding of this and can help debug the axis switching weirdness with me it would be greatly appreciated.